# Synchronise 2 repositories in git

Tags: linux, github, solaris

I have my main project hosted in GitHub. Everything is good and works.

Now I'm trying to create a Solaris port. I make myself an OpenSolaris VM installed Solaris Studio as compiler/IDE and built.

Everything works fine.

Now what I'm thinking is that since Solaris Studio is completely different IDE/compiler from MSVC/Anjuta/Xcode, I should create a different repository (NOT A FORK) and push Solaris stuff there.

The only problem is - code synchronization.

If I make the change in my main repository and push it to remote, I want my second repository to be updated as well with the changes to the *.cpp/.h files.

Is there exist some kind of hook to do that?

Or maybe I'm better off with creating a fork? But then changes to the build system will be overwritten.

Please advise.

This is the current structure for the main project:

```
Project folder -> main app folder (*.cpp, *.h, *.sln, Makefile.am/Makefile.in, xcodeproj folder)
                     |
                     ----> library 1 folder (*.cpp, *.h, *.sln, Makefile.am/Makefile.in, xcodeproj folder)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Or maybe I'm better off with creating a fork? But then changes to the build system will be overwritten.

I wouldn't even bother with a fork.

I would just make sure the build system is isolated in its own folder, which allows you to have in one repository two build configuration folders:

- one for a default environment
- one dedicated to a Solaris environment

That way, you can go on contributing to the code, from either one of those environments, without having to deal with any synchronization issue.

Comment: ,do you have any idea how to do it? I'm using MSVC on Windows, Anuta on Linux and Xcode on OSX. I also have multiple libraries (dll/so/dylib). And the files that are needed for generating the appropriate makefiles are in the appropriate directories. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: @Igor This is more a suggestion to configure your different build systems (which are working now) in order for them to run from two different subfolder of your main project. If you can do that, move the parts specific to said build systems in their own subfolders, you can make keep them in the same repository: each of them ignores the other.

Comment: I added my current directory structure in the OP. Can you suggest how to do that?

Comment: @Igor the idea is to not duplicate the sources, only the Makefile and other build-specific resources. Keep the sources were they were originally.